# Can't Install `pip` for `python 3.3` but worked fine for `python 2.7`

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I'm new to python but not programming. My goal is to learn Django for web development.

I've been trying to install the later versions of `python`, `pip` and `Django`. I could install `pip` for `python 2.7` just fine but now that I'm trying to install it on `python 3`, it gives me an error which I think is related to SSL certifications but not sure how to resolve it. My confusion is the fact that it worked fine once but doesn't happen again. I really appreciate the help.

My code is below:

```
~$> which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3
~$> which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
~$> pip -V
pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
~$> sudo python3 /Applications/get-pip.py 
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Gemeni/.pip/pip.log
~$>
```

I'm still very much stuck. I used a work around and installed pip...

easy_install pip==1.2.1

but the version is not 1.2.1 and I can't install anything else with pip now.

~$> pip install django

Downloading/unpacking django

Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django

Cleaning up...

No distributions at all found for django

Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Gemeni/.pip/pip.log

~$> pip --version

pip 1.5.6 from /Users/Gemeni/.virtualenvs/yara-project/lib/python3.3/site-packages (python 3.3)

Can someone please help me out to figure this out? I installed python3.4 at first but I saw that Django is not supporting it now. I comes with pip already installed. I read everywhere that it's a SSL issue and can be solved by modifying proxy setting but I'm not sure how it can be done. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

pip is for python2
pip3 is for python3

Try to install the package python3-pip with your distro package manager, then use pip3 to install Django. Come back if you get any other problem

Like:

```
~#>apt-get install python3-pip
~$>pip3 install django
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I forgot to mention I'm using a mac and apparently there's not a good way to use apt-get on mac. Can you suggest an alternative please?

Comment: You can try homebrew, I personally never used it, but can be a solutions http://brew.sh/

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.

I just did this


# download and install setuptools
curl -O https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py

python3 ez_setup.py

# download and install pip

curl -O https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py


I got the same SSL error.

Comment: see this link http://iainhunter.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/howto-install-python3-pip3-tornado-on-mac/

Comment: Thanks but the same issue happens in all scenarios

~$> sudo python3 get-pip.py

Downloading/unpacking pip

  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Gemeni/.pip/pip.log

Comment: I'm still very much stuck. I used a work around and installed pip... 

easy_install pip==1.2.1  

but the version is not 1.2.1 and I can't install anything else with pip now. 


~$> pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for django
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Gemeni/.pip/pip.log
~$> pip -version

Comment: This is weird, from where did you install python ? Try making a clean install from here, https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-341/ The Win32 Binaries is shipped with pip, maybe the Mac binaries too..

Comment: Thanks I got rid of Python 3.3 and went with python 3.4. It's not supporting mysql yet so I'm not sure what to do about that right now. I guess I'll use the sqllite for now until the mysql support comes out. Thanks a lot for all the comments.