# Installing packages using pip give SSL error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ssl, pip

I recently started learning Python, am new to Python but not to programming. I have four machines on which I was able to install the Django and Python seamlessly. On the fifth machine that is a Mac Book Pro OS 10.6.8 I am able to install Django (or for that matter any other package) for Python2.6 but get the following error if I try it for Python 3.4.1

```
Downloading/unpacking django
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for django
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/himmy/.pip/pip.log
```

I tried searching the web and the closest I found was

[Can't Install `pip` for `python 3.3` but worked fine for `python 2.7`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23937629/cant-install-pip-for-python-3-3-but-worked-fine-for-python-2-7)

which doesn't really solve the problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: just to check: A) is your network behind a proxy B) from your mac, can you bring up https://pypi.python.org/simple via say curl.  (No idea why this would be different for 3.3 vs 2.7 though I do seem to recall pip giving some warnings about how it was going to enforce https checking)

Comment: Also, as hinted by your linked... are you doing pip install or pip3 install for the python 3.4 version

Comment: @Foon A) I am not using any proxy. On my new macbook pro the installation worked seamlessly. b) Yes I am able to get  pypi.python.org/simple using curl. I am using the following command **pip3 install Django**

Comment: So after some more digging I found a solution which I dont think is neat at all but works. Downgrading pip to version 1.2 solves the problem. The easiest way to achieve this **curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz 
tar xvfz pip-1.2.1.tar.gz 
cd pip-1.2.1 
python setup.py  install**

Comment: *"Installing packages using pip give SSL error"* - what, exactly, is the SSL error. I can't seem to parse it from the question. Some relevant pieces from `pip.log` would probably be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [a comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268110/installing-packages-using-pip-give-ssl-error#comment39373973_25268110):

> Downgrading pip to version 1.2 solves the problem. The easiest way to
>   achieve this is:
>
> ```
> curl -O pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-1.2.1.tar.gz tar xvfz pip-1.2.1.tar.gz cd pip-1.2.1 python setup.py install
> ```